# Most efficient way to script toggle buttons on and off functionality

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

I wrote a bit of code that changes the visual state of a button (whichever button is clicked gets highlighted blue and returns all other buttons back to their default color). It seems to work fine but it feels cumbersome. Is there a more efficient/succinct way to re-write my code? Many thanks!

```
using UnityEngine ;
using System.Collections ;
using UnityEngine.UI ;

public class ToolButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color activeColor ;
    public Color inactiveColor ;
    public GameObject iconBG ;
    public Button ink, brush, crayon, pencil, spray, eraser, chnageColor, brushSize, undo, redo, clear, newAnimal ;
    public GameObject inkIconBG, brushIconBG, crayonIconBG, pencilIconBG, sprayIconBG, eraserIconBG, changeColorIconBG, brushSizeIconBG ;

    void Start ()
    {
        inactiveColor = iconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color ;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void buttonCallBack (Button buttonClicked)
    {
        //Change Color Palette Button clicked
        if (buttonClicked == ink)
        {
            inkIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = activeColor ;
        } else if (buttonClicked != ink)
        {
            inkIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = inactiveColor ;
        }

        if (buttonClicked == brush)
        {
            brushIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = activeColor ;
        } else if (buttonClicked != brush)
        {
            brushIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = inactiveColor ;
        }

        if (buttonClicked == crayon)
        {
            crayonIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = activeColor ;
        } else if (buttonClicked != crayon)
        {
            crayonIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = inactiveColor ;
        }

        if (buttonClicked == pencil)
        {
            pencilIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = activeColor ;
        } else if (buttonClicked != pencil)
        {
            pencilIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = inactiveColor ;
        }

        if (buttonClicked == spray)
        {
            sprayIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = activeColor ;
        } else if (buttonClicked != spray)
        {
            sprayIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = inactiveColor ;
        }

        if (buttonClicked == eraser)
        {
            eraserIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = activeColor ;
        } else if (buttonClicked != eraser)
        {
            eraserIconBG.GetComponent <Image> ().color = inactiveColor ;
        }
    }

    void OnEnable ()
    {
        ink.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (ink)) ;
        brush.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (brush)) ;
        crayon.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (crayon)) ;
        pencil.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (pencil)) ;
        spray.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (spray)) ;
        eraser.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (eraser)) ;
    }


    void OnDisable ()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: are you aware about the Toggle Group Component?

Comment: I know of it @Aizen but I've not used it before.

Comment: Toggle Component chooses only one Component (in your case a button) and you can change the Look or color of the component. And automatically, the others will be set into their default state. Off-course on your own custom definition. This should be the best time for you to learn about the component, so you would save a lot of time. Recreating a component that Unity3D already provides for you.

Comment: @Aizen a `Button` is not the-same thing  as `Toggle`. .`Toggle Group` is used for `Toggle` components. `Toggle` is like a switch. `Button` is used to detect simple click on an image. Both act differently and `Toggle Group` is not appropriate for this.

Comment: "button is not the same as toggle" Well DUH!. "Toggle Group is used for Toggle components" DUH DUH!? "Button is used to detect simple click on an image"  NO.... DUH.... NO.. Its a Button not an image. Check the code. He wants to toggle Button from Inactive to Active, at the same time Effecting the Other Buttons. Try again. Captain Obvious.

Comment: @Aizen Duh everywhere but you told OP to use `Toggle Group` on a `Button`..... Op wants to use a `Button` for this. I am glad you know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with array would have been better but the problem is that you would lose the names of your Buttons and GameObjects making it hard to modify your code later on.

You can use `Dictionary` for this. Make a `Button`--`GameObject` pair then manually add each `Button` to match each Icon/GameObject. You can then loop through it when `Button` is clicked, compare the the `Button` that was clicked with the key in the `Dictionary`, then assign `activeColor` or `inactiveColor` based on the comparison result.

**Note**: If you add more Buttons and Icons, you must add them too to the `pairButtonIcon()` function.

*Anyone wondering why I didn't use `foreach` loop over the `Dictionary`, that's because it allocates memory in Unity.*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ToolButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color activeColor;
    public Color inactiveColor;
    public GameObject iconBG;
    public Button ink, brush, crayon, pencil, spray, eraser, chnageColor, brushSize, undo, redo, clear, newAnimal;
    public GameObject inkIconBG, brushIconBG, crayonIconBG, pencilIconBG, sprayIconBG, eraserIconBG, changeColorIconBG, brushSizeIconBG;

    Dictionary<Button, GameObject> buttonIconPair = new Dictionary<Button, GameObject>();

    void pairButtonIcon()
    {
        buttonIconPair.Add(ink, inkIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(brush, brushIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(crayon, crayonIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(pencil, pencilIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(spray, sprayIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(eraser, eraserIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(chnageColor, changeColorIconBG);
        buttonIconPair.Add(brushSize, brushSizeIconBG);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        pairButtonIcon();
        inactiveColor = iconBG.GetComponent<Image>().color;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void buttonCallBack(Button buttonClicked)
    {

        //My Code
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonIconPair.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = buttonIconPair.ElementAt(i);
            var itemKey = item.Key;
            var itemValue = item.Value;

            if (buttonClicked == itemKey)
            {
                itemValue.GetComponent<Image>().color = activeColor;
            }
            else
            {
                itemValue.GetComponent<Image>().color = inactiveColor;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        ink.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(ink));
        brush.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(brush));
        crayon.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(crayon));
        pencil.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(pencil));
        spray.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(spray));
        eraser.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(eraser));
    }


    void OnDisable()
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: You can also use multiple `Lists` then store `Button` and GameObject/Icon on each one.

```
public class ToolButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color activeColor;
    public Color inactiveColor;
    public GameObject iconBG;
    public Button ink, brush, crayon, pencil, spray, eraser, chnageColor, brushSize, undo, redo, clear, newAnimal;
    public GameObject inkIconBG, brushIconBG, crayonIconBG, pencilIconBG, sprayIconBG, eraserIconBG, changeColorIconBG, brushSizeIconBG;

    List<Button> button = new List<Button>();
    List<GameObject> iconGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    void pairButtonIcon()
    {
        button.Add(ink);
        iconGameObjects.Add(inkIconBG);

        button.Add(brush);
        iconGameObjects.Add(brushIconBG);

        button.Add(crayon);
        iconGameObjects.Add(crayonIconBG);

        button.Add(pencil);
        iconGameObjects.Add(pencilIconBG);

        button.Add(spray);
        iconGameObjects.Add(sprayIconBG);

        button.Add(eraser);
        iconGameObjects.Add(eraserIconBG);

        button.Add(chnageColor);
        iconGameObjects.Add(changeColorIconBG);

        button.Add(brushSize);
        iconGameObjects.Add(brushSizeIconBG);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        pairButtonIcon();
        inactiveColor = iconBG.GetComponent<Image>().color;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void buttonCallBack(Button buttonClicked)
    {

        //My Code
        for (int i = 0; i < button.Count; i++)
        {
            if (buttonClicked == button[i])
            {
                iconGameObjects[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = activeColor;
            }
            else
            {
                iconGameObjects[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = inactiveColor;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        ink.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(ink));
        brush.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(brush));
        crayon.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(crayon));
        pencil.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(pencil));
        spray.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(spray));
        eraser.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(eraser));
    }


    void OnDisable()
    {

    }
}
```